# Layout Slider Material Design

Tags: html, css, materialize

I can not make the slider consume the entire area of the index , note that half of the section "structure" is seen on the site , already I tried everything but I'm not good with CSS .

[My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/vfwd6uuz/)

```
   <div id="intro" class="section scrollspy">

  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-XANwq8Lfs3Y/Tg5owyTsXII/AAAAAAAAAAs/0w3j13_dgKc/s320/canuto008.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Lazer a seu alcance.</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Espaço pensado e estruturado para o seu lazer.</h5>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the slider take up the full screen [like this](http://materializecss.com/fullscreen-slider-demo.html)?

If so, try adding the `full_width` option to your slider initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
});
```